# Browse file and store on default path local disc (without browse window) in as3(AIR APP)

Tags: file, actionscript-3, filereference

I need some help to store browsed file in native path of AIR APP.
where I can select file by browsing from locale and then it will store to fixed path without save window.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Comment: Thank you Marton Pallagi